# Is there a way to find the Frame name from Firebug without using console?

Tags: iframe, firebug, ui-automation, firepath

I have been trying to find if there is any way to find out the iframe name from Firebug, without having to use its built-in console.

I am aware that window.frames[x] will switch the window handle to "x"frame, but is there any way to just find out the name of the frame without having to use console, so that I can use the frame name in my Automation script?

I am now using Firepath to get the name of the frame, however, I was wondering if the same can be done using Firebug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to find frames within the DOM structure is to use the [*HTML* panel´s search](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Search) (which allows to search for XPaths). So, just type in `//frame` (or `//iframe` for iframes) and you´ll be able to navigate through the different / elements.

The frames are also listed within the [*DOM* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DOM_Panel).

Firebug also offers you a way to switch between different frame contexts via the [cd() command](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#cd.28window.29), but it does not have a visual option for that.
Though the Firefox DevTools [implement a button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/tools/Working_with_iframes), which lists the different frames in a popup menu.

If you mean the `name` attribute when you speak about 'name', you can also get them easily using the following code:

```
var frames = document.querySelectorAll("frame, iframe");
var frameNames = [];
for (var i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
  frameNames.push(frames[0].getAttribute("name"));
}
```